# Ignoring users in chat - force them to "ignore" you?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I was thinking that it might be worthwhile to add a functionality that if you ignore a user (bob), it forces the same functionality on them with your messages?

For example I've seen people talking about a bob, all of which have bob ignored, however bob can still see all the messages about them.

So I was thinking it might be worthwhile adding in a functionality that when a user ignores bob, bob can no longer see the messages from that user?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this about me?

Comment: @UniKitty no, it's about ignored users in chat.

Comment: Because last I checked people are ignoring me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this would be a good idea. As a chat user, I'd like to choose myself whose messages I see and whose I don't. It would be pretty annoying to notice that I cannot see someone else's messages, just because they ignored me.

Having this feature request implemented would make that you partially lose control of whose messages you (don't) see, and I (and probably other people too) would find that very annoying.

Comment: Another reason this isn't a good idea is that it would break the anonymity of the feature. If I happen to notice that I don't see messages from people I haven't manually ignored, then I'd know they are ignoring me. That's... not good.

Comment: +1 (for answer and comment) - Although, at least then you'd know who doesn't like you. Which would be terrible if you went into chat and there were 40 users but no messages to see... :(